# PC Not Sleeping Due to Youtube Video Continuously Playing All Night

Tags: windows-10, sleep, youtube

Whenever I leave a Youtube video on, whether it is autoplaying or not, it can just be 1 long YouTube video of classical music for instance. Even though I have my PC set up to sleep after 1 hour, it does not do so because the YouTube video is making it seem as if there is still activity going on. I searched many threads on SuperUser, and could not seem to find any solution on how to get your PC to sleep if you have a video playing.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this behavior in Group Policy:

- Run the Group Policy Editor `gpedit.msc`
- Open
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
  Power Management > Sleep Settings*
- Set "Allow Applications to Prevent Automatic Sleep" to Disabled.
  There are two options, one for "on battery" and one for "plugged in",
  so for a laptop you might want to set both.
- Reboot (might not be necessary).

Comment: @harrymc I tried this, it does not work. Thanks for trying to help though, I appreciate it!

Comment: Which browser are you using?